# Field data not showing on front end after submit

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm submitting a form that updates Wordpress [ACF field data using the update_field function](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/). This works great but the problem I have is that the data gets submitted, it adds it to the correct ACF fields in Wordpress but I then I have refresh the page manually to see the new data on the front end.

**How can I submit the data then show it on the first reload?**

```
<form action="#" class="forum-post-comment-form" id="forum-comment-<?php echo $counter; ?>" method="get">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here" class="forum-comment-box" id="forum-comment-<?php echo $counter; ?>" name="forum-comment-<?php echo $counter; ?>">
    <span><input type="submit" class="comment-submit-btn" name="submit-<?php echo $counter; ?>" value=""></span>
  </input>
</form>

<?php
$value = array();
if( have_rows( 'comments', $postid ) ):
  while( have_rows( 'comments', $postid ) ): the_row();
    $time_posted = get_sub_field( 'time', $postid );
    $posted = get_sub_field( 'posted_by', $postid );
    $comment = get_sub_field( 'comment', $postid );
    $answerresponse = get_sub_field( 'answer', $postid );

    $value[] = array(
      "time"        => $time_posted,
      "posted_by"   => $posted,
      "comment"     => $comment,
      "answer"          => $answerresponse
    );
  endwhile;
endif;

$submit = "submit-" . $counter;
if(isset($_POST[$submit])){
  $form = "forum-comment-" . $counter;
  $finalanswer = "answer-" . $counter;
  $finalanswer = $_POST[$finalanswer];
  $comment = $_POST[$form];

  //if ($comment != "") {
    $time_posted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

    // Comments
    $postid = get_the_id();
    $field_key = "field_5c90d272c7ca9";

    $value[] = array(
      "time"          => $time_posted,
      "posted_by"     => $current_user->ID,
      "answer"              => $finalanswer,
      "comment"       => $comment,
    );

    update_field( $field_key, $value, $postid );
  //}
}
?>
```

ACF field layouts:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_5c90d20a076ab',
    'title' => 'Comments',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_5c90d272c7ca9',
            'label' => 'Comments',
            'name' => 'comments',
            'type' => 'repeater',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'collapsed' => '',
            'min' => 0,
            'max' => 0,
            'layout' => 'block',
            'button_label' => 'Add Comment',
            'sub_fields' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_5c90f06883914',
                    'label' => 'Time',
                    'name' => 'time',
                    'type' => 'date_time_picker',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array(
                        'width' => '33',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'display_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                    'return_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                    'first_day' => 1,
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_5c90ee4fc7cac',
                    'label' => 'Posted by',
                    'name' => 'posted_by',
                    'type' => 'user',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array(
                        'width' => '33',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'role' => '',
                    'allow_null' => 0,
                    'multiple' => 0,
                    'return_format' => 'array',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_5c90d38cc7cab',
                    'label' => 'Answer?',
                    'name' => 'answer',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'instructions' => 'Change to "Yes" to mark as the answer',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array(
                        'width' => '33',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'default_value' => 'No',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'prepend' => '',
                    'append' => '',
                    'maxlength' => '',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'field_5c90d28ac7caa',
                    'label' => 'Comment',
                    'name' => 'comment',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'instructions' => '',
                    'required' => 0,
                    'conditional_logic' => 0,
                    'wrapper' => array(
                        'width' => '100',
                        'class' => '',
                        'id' => '',
                    ),
                    'default_value' => '',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'maxlength' => '',
                    'rows' => '',
                    'new_lines' => '',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'forum',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'position' => 'normal',
    'style' => 'default',
    'label_placement' => 'top',
    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
    'hide_on_screen' => array(
        0 => 'excerpt',
        1 => 'discussion',
        2 => 'comments',
        3 => 'slug',
        4 => 'author',
        5 => 'format',
        6 => 'page_attributes',
        7 => 'featured_image',
        8 => 'categories',
        9 => 'tags',
        10 => 'send-trackbacks',
    ),
    'active' => true,
    'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `$value = get_field( $field_key ); $value[] = [ ... new data ... ]; update_field( $field_key, $value ); $value = get_field( $field_key );` ?

Comment: Hi Can you please share a video of your problem it will be better

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm outputting all my data above this. It all displays fine but anything in the form needs to be submitted, then the page refreshed for a second time for it to show.

Comment: @Rob, "above this" - sorry, what is the "this"? The form? Or do you display the data from the `$value` array? Which means right below the form? Can you export your ACF field settings so we could (hopefully) reproduce the issue? Or is the `comments` a repeater or flexible content field? (sorry for the many questions..)

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry for some clarity - `comments` is a repeater. So for each post I'm looping through and outputting the comments for that post, then after the comments data has been output there's the form (shown in the question above) then the `update_field` function below that (also in the question above). This whole block is repeated for each post. So there's a question then some comments underneath it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Rob. So do you need to do anything with the `$value` array after calling the `update_field()`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Not after the `update_date` function no. Just each post needs to show the new data after the submission. I've been trying various things in the mean time but no luck so far. I just find it strange that on submit it adds the data to the correct fields yet I need to refresh the page again... it's like there's some kind of cache issue or something???

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's not caching issue. What's the `$counter`? How/where is it defined?

Comment: @SallyCJ That's set at the very top of the query - `// Run the query $the_query = new WP_Query($args); if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $counter = 1; ?>`. It's just so I can target each individual post when it loops through them all

Comment: Ok, @Rob. I (think I) actually know what happened and what should be done. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: @SallyCJ Great thanks so much, it's really beaten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after the comments data has been output there's the form (shown in the
>   question above) then the `update_field` function below that (also in
>   the question above)

So actually, there's the problem — you should update the field *before* the page is rendered and not after.

### Working Solution

So I'm posting the form to `wp-admin/admin-post.php` which fires the hook [`admin_post_{action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/) (for authenticated users) or [`admin_post_nopriv_{action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_nopriv_action/) (for non-authenticated users). You could use the `init` hook or any similar hook, but I think the `admin-post.php` is a good gateway to handle form submissions, be it via the `GET` or `POST` method — if you're familiar with the `wp_ajax_{action}`, then `admin_post_{action}` is similar to that, except for **non-AJAX** requests.

**The HTML + PHP form**

```php
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" class="forum-post-comment-form" id="forum-comment-<?php echo $counter; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here" class="forum-comment-box" id="forum-comment-<?php echo $counter; ?>" name="forum_comment" />

  <!-- I manually added these radios; make sure to edit the code.. -->
  <div>
    Mark as the answer?
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="Yes" /> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="No" /> No</label>
  </div>

  <!-- Hidden data for add_forum_comment() which updates the field. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add-forum-comment" />

  <span><input type="submit" class="comment-submit-btn" name="submit" value=""></span>
</form>
```

**PHP function which processes the form's submission**

```php
add_action( 'admin_post_add-forum-comment', 'add_forum_comment' );        // for authenticated users
//add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add-forum-comment', 'add_forum_comment' ); // for non-authenticated users
function add_forum_comment() {
    // Check if the post is valid.
    $postid = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );
    if ( ! $post = get_post( $postid ) ) {
        wp_die( 'The post does not exist.' );
    }

    // Check if we've got a valid comment.
    $posted_comment = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'forum_comment' );
    if ( ! $posted_comment ) {
        // Redirect back to the post.
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $postid ) );
        exit;
    }


    // Initialize $value and fill it with existing values.
    $value = array();
    if( have_rows( 'comments', $postid ) ):
      while( have_rows( 'comments', $postid ) ): the_row();
        $time_posted = get_sub_field( 'time', $postid );
        $posted = get_sub_field( 'posted_by', $postid );
        $comment = get_sub_field( 'comment', $postid );
        $answerresponse = get_sub_field( 'answer', $postid );

        $value[] = array(
          "time"      => $time_posted,
          "posted_by" => $posted,
          "comment"   => $comment,
          'answer'    => $answerresponse,
        );
      endwhile;
    endif;


    // Now update the ACF field.
    $counter = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'counter' );
    $finalanswer = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'answer' );

    $time_posted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

    // Comments
    $field_key = "field_5c90d272c7ca9";

    $value[] = array(
      "time"      => $time_posted,
      "posted_by" => get_current_user_id(),
      'answer'    => $finalanswer,
      "comment"   => $posted_comment,
    );

    update_field( $field_key, $value, $postid );


    // Redirect back to the post.
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $postid ) );
    exit;

}
```

Tried and tested working. And you don't have to use the exact same code, but I hope the code helps you. Also, I use `get_current_user_id()` to get the ID of the current user.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! Had to make a few minor adjustments but it's all working now. You always give such detailed answers!

Comment: Yes, I always try to. :) And in the code, I think you may not need to pass the `$counter` to the PHP function, but I kept the code there for your reference.